# Boolean equation - bitwise AND operator

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have equation:
(x AND B) XOR x = C
where x - is unknown variable, B and C are constant.

I need just one solution x that will satisfy this equation. How I can do this?

Comment: if you don't know or like boolean algebra, just write the true table.

Answer (score 2):

There exists no solution that will satisfy all cases. If $B$ and $C$ are true, then no values of $x$ satisfy the equation.